# random use in app

Tags: iphone

how can an array be created that randomizes results from 3 different values 0,1,2 and then makes 2 combinations of those

for example :
i have

```
int values[3] = {0,1,2}
blah = values[arc4random() %3];
```

i tried using this from the arc4random help post on this site however when i do the above the app crashes. Im a begginer to arc4random and cant figure a solution to this since there isnt enough documents online to help me. 
Furthermore how can i choose 2 items from blah to be displayed?

Comment: You'll have to rephrase your question. If you have 3 values, there is only one combination of 3 possible.

Comment: i mean if i have 0,1,2, i want blah to be able to equal 2 or 3 or 1 or 2 u get what i mean??

Comment: uh, no, not really.  do you want to sum 2 random numbers from `values[]`?

Comment: i have lets say 100 combinations in my app. i want to be able to get 20 values of those randomly and be able to use those values one after each other (in their random order) to be able display those values in some random order. You understood my situation very well at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for one you're missing a `;`

```
int values[3] = {0,1,2}; //<-- here
int blah = values[arc4random() %3];
NSLog(@"Value: %d",blah);
```

Second, the above compiles just fine.

Third, I think you want to do this, but as @Shaggy Frog mentioned, your question is kindof unclear:

```
int combo[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    combo[i] = values[arc4random() %3];
}
```

Which should give you a random "combination" of the values in `values[]`.  [Combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) has a specific definition, as well as [permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

I believe what you want is a set of 3 numbers chosen at random from `values[]`.  If you *do* need permutations, get comfy with [Dijkstra](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/permutation.html).

---

[Edit]

To get what you specified in the comment, you can do this:

```
int values[3] = {0,1,2}; 
int sum;
switch (arc4random()%3) {
case 0:
    sum = values[1] + values[2];
    break;
case 1:
    sum = values[0] + values[2];
    break;
case 2:
    sum = values[1] + values[0];
    break;
}
```

---

[Edit]

Or, you can do this:

```
int values[3] = {0,1,2}; 
int blah[2];
int index;
switch (arc4random()%3) {
case 0:
    index = arc4random()%2;
    blah[index] = values[1];
    blah[1-index] = values[2];
    break;
case 1:
    index = arc4random()%2;
    blah[index] = values[0];
    blah[1-index] = values[2];
    break;
case 2:
    index = arc4random()%2;
    blah[index] = values[1];
    blah[1-index] = values[0];
    break;
}
```

a [card drawing algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881146/how-to-program-drawing-from-a-deck-of-card-where-value-and-suit-is-unimportant) may also suit your needs.

Comment: yes this is what im looking for however how can the case 0,1,2 be randomized to contain only 2 "values" from the 3 randomly?